Sending email via gmail acoount in bash
Trying to send email in bash by gmail at first I installed ssmtp then opened configuration file in this path : /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
Update it to include my Gmail details:
AuthMethod=LOGIN  
Host=smtp.gmail.com  
Port=587  
FromLineOverride=YES  
AuthUser=my_email@gmail.com  
AuthPass=my_password  
UseSTARTTLS=YES

using this bash script to send email:
#!/bin/bash  

TO="abc@abs.com"  
SUBJECT="Subject Here"  
BODY="Body of the email."  

echo "$BODY" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO"

after running countered with this error :
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Trying to troubleshoot, I used this command to test whether simple mailing works or not
 echo "Test email body" | mail -s "Test Subject" abc@abs.com

and again countered with the same error....
and this is the result of checking mail logs:
tail -f /var/log/mail.log


 sSMTP[710]: Unable to locate mailhub
 sSMTP[710]: Cannot open mailhub:25
 sSMTP[721]: Unable to set Host="smtp.gmail.com"
 sSMTP[721]: Unable to set Port="587"
 sSMTP[721]: Unable to locate mailhub
 sSMTP[721]: Cannot open mailhub:25
 sSMTP[734]: Unable to set Host="smtp.gmail.com"
 sSMTP[734]: Unable to set Port="587"
 sSMTP[734]: Unable to locate mailhub
 sSMTP[734]: Cannot open mailhub:25

geeksforgeeks.org/send-mails-using-a-bash-script

By default gmail requires MFA, unless you configure said account with an application password

Add the Google link that you are following its instructions to send emails in Bash.

The link you have provided uses a curl command to send the email, but you are using the mail command here. What is the difference between these two? Are you sure they do the same thing? By the way, it seems you are using your regular username/password, while you are supposed to get a gapp password from Gmail to make this feature work.
